# Visual Basic Slot Machine

Tags: string, visual-studio-2015, typeconverter

I'm hoping the community can help me out. I'm having a small issue with my program. It works perfectly as long as the user inputs a value in the textbox. However, when I test the code without input, it still displays the message as if the user lost ("Please play again!"). Also, on occasion, it will display an error that says it can't convert "intResult = CInt(strBet)". Any ideas are appreciated.

```
' Declare public variables to call later.
Dim intA As Integer
Dim intB As Integer
Dim intC As Integer
Dim intResult As Integer
Dim rnd As New Random
Dim strBet As String
Dim intCount As Integer

Private Sub btnSpin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSpin.Click

    ' Variable to hold user input
    strBet = txtBet.Text

    ' Generate random numbers to randomize PictureBox
    intA = rnd.Next(1, 10)
    intB = rnd.Next(1, 10)
    intC = rnd.Next(1, 10)

    ' Check for numeric input.
    If Not IsNumeric(strBet) Then
        txtBet.Text = String.Empty
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value.")
        txtBet.Focus()
        Reset()

    ElseIf txtBet.Text = String.Empty Then
        btnSpin.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("Enter your bet." &
                        "Please use a numeric value.")
        SlotTimer.Stop()
        txtBet.Focus()
        Reset()

        ' Reset the results, game timer, and counter to 0.
    Else
        intResult = 0
        intCount = 0
        SlotTimer.Start()
    End If

    ' Check for matching values.
    If intA = intB And intB = intC Then
        intResult = CInt(strBet)
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You won " & (intResult * 3).ToString("c"))
        txtBet.Focus()

    ElseIf intA = intB Then
        intResult = CInt(strBet)
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You won " & (intResult * 2).ToString("c"))
        txtBet.Focus()

    ElseIf intA = intC Then
        intResult = CInt(strBet)
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You won " & (intResult * 2).ToString("c"))
        txtBet.Focus()

    ElseIf intB = intC Then
        intResult = CInt(strBet)
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations! You won " & (intResult * 2).ToString("c"))
        txtBet.Focus()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please play again!")
        txtBet.Focus()
    End If

    ' Change images between spins.
    changeImageA(picImageOne, 0)
    changeImageA(picImageTwo, 0)
    changeImageA(picImageThree, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub changeImageA(ByVal pic As PictureBox, ByVal int As Integer)

    ' Create function to control PictureBox with Integers
    Select Case int
        Case 1
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Apple

        Case 2
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Banana

        Case 3
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Cherries

        Case 4
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Grapes

        Case 5
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Lemon

        Case 6
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Lime

        Case 7
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Orange

        Case 8
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Pear

        Case 9
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Strawberry

        Case 10
            pic.Image = My.Resources.Watermelon
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub SlotTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SlotTimer.Tick

    ' Call counter and increase it by one.
    intCount += 1

    ' Randomize the integer count to change picture images.
    Randomize()
    If intCount = 1 Then
        changeImageA(picImageOne, intA)
    ElseIf intCount = 3 Then
        changeImageA(picImageTwo, intB)
    ElseIf intCount = 5 Then
        changeImageA(picImageThree, intC)
        SlotTimer.Stop()
        btnSpin.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    ' Close the form
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub txtBet_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBet.TextChanged
    ' Allows user to press the "Enter" key instead of click "Spin".
    Me.AcceptButton = btnSpin
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: VB.NET helper functions, like IsNumeric() and Val(), are pretty forgiving.  You are making it a lot worse by actually checking but then just plowing on as though the user entered a correct value.  Use the `Return` statement to bail out.  Use `Integer.TryParse()` for the most correct test.  And verify the entered value, a value that is not between 1 and 10 is of course nonsense.  The Validating event can be useful to force the user to enter a correct value.

Comment: Return worked. Thank you.

Comment: I have a follow up question. I apologize. I just saw it as a requirement. What would be the best way to store the total amount of money entered into the slot machine during this session and the total amount won when the user exits the program?

Comment: You should add two new instance variables: one for the total amount spent, one for the total amount received. Everytime the user inputs a new value, you can simply add this new amount to the existing one (total amount spent). Do the same for the total amount received.